# How to make this slider auto play

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

how can i make this java script code to auto play the slider and How to add mouse-over pause function

```js
$(function() {
  $('.owl-carousel.testimonial-carousel').owlCarousel({
    nav: true,
    navText: ['<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>', '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>'],
    dots: false,
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 1,
      },
      750: {
        items: 2,
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Search the [doc](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/autoplay.html).

Answer (score 1):

Owl Carousel has the two options you are looking for, **autoplay** and **autoplayHoverPause**.

Try this:

```
$('.owl-carousel.testimonial-carousel').owlCarousel({
    nav: true,
    navText: ['<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>', '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>'],
    dots: false,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayHoverPause: true,
    loop: true,
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 1,
      },
      750: {
        items: 2,
      }
    }
  });
```

You can find a list of all the available options here: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use this plugin https://owlcarousel2.github.io , add `autoplay: true` property for autoplay.

For pause on "mouseover", add `autoplayHoverPause: true` property:

```
$(function() {
  $('.owl-carousel.testimonial-carousel').owlCarousel({
    nav: true,
    navText: ['<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>', '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>'],
    dots: false,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayHoverPause: true,
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 1,
      },
      750: {
        items: 2,
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: The loop option won't autoplay the slider, you need the autoplay option set to true.

Comment: I have read the documentation and it is
autoplay: true,
and
autoplayHoverPause: true,